# How to update a specific value in all query results (rows) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy query and I wish to update a specific field in all the items returned from the query something like:

```
items = MyModel.query().filter(
        MyModel.status == 'OK',
    )
with db.managed_session() as s:
   items.update(status_date=datetime.today())
```

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use:

```
session.query(MyModel).\
        filter(MyModel.status == 'OK').\
        update({'status_date': datetime.today()})
```

I think that in your example is missing the {} in the update.

Comment: Hello @Ektor I get an error when I use update like this. The error says: `Can't call Query.update() or Query.delete() when order_by() has been called`

Comment: A never mind I figured it out, I was using a custom wrapper for the  `query` which had an `order_by()` in it. I switched to a query without ordering and it worked.